# TensorFlow: Sending input to an exported model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Scenario: I have exported a TF model and I have the .pb file. The model is a simple classifier which has been trained on images. THe model takes an image as an input and provides whether the image belongs to a certain category with a probability score.

I am using python and am loading the model using below. 
graph = load_graph('model.pb')

But unable to figure out a way to send an image as input and retrieve results. What attributes should I used to send input and receive results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it in tensorflow. The simplest way is using a feed_dict. You first need to locate your input tensor, output_tensor from the model and then use feed dict to feed a new input and get a new output 
Example:

```
    input_place_holder = model.input_place_holder
    out_put = model.output_tensor
    current_input = your_img_input
    result = model.session.run([out_put], feed_dict={input_place_holder: current_input})
```

A more advanced method to feed input into a model is using tensorflow serving (which has better performance etc)